# Website is not accessible from server which is using proxy

Tags: iis, web-hosting

I hosted a website in a win 2008 R2 server which runs in private domain.

I set up bindings for port 80 and 443 for http & https respectively.

Created inbound rule for port 80 and 443 also in windows firewall.

After doing all this, i am still not able to access my website from remote machine.

IE : Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage.

Chrome : Oops! Google Chrome could not find xxxxxx

Tried accessing website by ip address but no luck.

I tried to ping that server but it says

TTL expired in Transit.

Now i found some more information over internet to check if the server is using any kind of proxy in between.

I found my IP address at www.getip.com, but ipconfig/all gives me a different IP address. Is it really a problem if we use proxy ?

I am not sure if i have concluded it correctly. But is there any way out to resolve this issue?

Update :::

I figured it out. I have to call that website with external IP address. due to the proxy settings i was not able to call that website by the server's IP or name of that machine.

Comment: What do you mean by "private domain" ?

Comment: The server was hosted on Internet whereas I was trying to connect it from intranet. And the intranet has some policy and constrains while accessing outside machines..

Comment: Your question as too few details to perform a meaningful diagnosis and provide a suggestion or solution. Could you edit your question and provide more details --- [1] what is your network set up like? [2] What is this restrictive intranet policy you are talking about? [3] You say your website is on the Internet... is it a shared hosting, VPS, dedicated server or a cloud setup? [4] Is the website hosted on a Windows or a Linux server?